# How to append 2 or more columns together inside of a SQL select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, append, grouping

Environment: Oracle.

Example Data:

`select col1, col2, col3 from tableName` produces this:

```
COL1      COL2      COL3
The       Word      Was
Value1    Value2    Value3
I         Am        Table
```

I would like to have something like this:
`select (col1 + col2 + col3) as GroupCol from tableName` to produce this:

```
GROUPCOL
TheWordWas
Value1Value2Value4
IAmTable
```

One column that encompasses three columns together as one.

This will be used to append ten different location columns together into on field when running a select statement.  **This has to be at the SQL level** and not above it in some report tier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `||` operator.

```
SELECT COL1 || COL2 || COL3
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @George.  you beat the other guy to it by a minute

Comment: Actually, he beat me to it -- make sure he gets your accepted vote if it solves your problem. :)